# Format date in SELECT * query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to format a date field in a SELECT * query? I want to get all of the columns from my table but need a different format from the date.

Something like:

```
SELECT *, FORMATDATE(date,'%m-%d-%y') AS date FROM my_table;
```

or do I have to process it in php after the query?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: @cubetwo1729: w3schools has some correct stuff but also many totally wrong. Example is the [CHECK constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) which do not work at all in MySQL ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d-%y") AS date FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Y2K police here.  "%m-%d-%Y" (%Y -> 4 digit year, %y -> 2 digit year) would most likely be preferred if at all possible.

Comment: I was close with my code! Is there a way to do it without creating a new field in the result?

Comment: @PGrau you mean you don't want to return the date field as well as the formatted date field? Then just remove the original date field from your SELECT. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d-%y") AS 'date', col1, col2, col3 FROM ...`

Comment: @Ben I have a LOT of columns, I was hoping to avoid listing them. I take it that isn't possible?

Comment: @Pgrau, no and `SELECT *` is generally considered bad form.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(your_date_field_name,'%m-%d-%y') AS whatever FROM your_table_name_here;
```

the result is something like this

**09-22-11**

as opposed to this

**2011-02-02 15:42:51**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `FORMATDATE` is, but you can use `DATE-FORMAT`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing application containing different timezones and formats better practice will be using UNIX timestamp stored in int(8) field, otherwise you can format date fields in queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can put name of column in back of date_format. like this :

```
$rs = mysql_query("select  blablabla,DATE_FORMAT(name_column, '%d-%b-%y | %H:%i')name_column,DATE_FORMAT(name_column2, '%d-%b-%y | %H:%i')as name_column2 from db ORDER BY id DESC limit $offset,$rows");
```

or you can put "as"
yes, you must select one by one. its work !!!!

Answer (score 0):

in the above solutions the select first extract all columns, then the date column with a requested format, this means that the date columns is returned twice, once in default format and once in requested format. Actually if you want to change the format of 1, 2 ou 3 date columns from you table and you also want to avoid duplicate data returned, you shall remove "*" from the request and name each and every column instead, correct?

is there a way to ask mysql to change the format of all the datetime columns and ignore the rest with a single command?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30971609)