# Display a date format from MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format date in SELECT * query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087363/format-date-in-select-query)

How to get a date format like this "October 5, 2010 2:15pm" from database.

Comment: Please, look at other posts before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087363/format-date-in-select-query

Comment: see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [**DATE_FORMAT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(current_timestamp(), '%M %e, %Y %h:%i%p');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work - `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %e, %Y %h:%i%p');`

Please read more on DATE_FORMAT [in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)