# Select query date format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How to format date on select query?

current code:

```
SELECT id, status, TransactionDate FROM Transaction
```

result **Mon Mar 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)**

what ive done so far:

```
SELECT id, status, DATE_FORMAT(TransactionDate, '%m-%d-%y') FROM Transaction
```

result **null**

reference: [Format date in SELECT * query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087363/format-date-in-select-query)

Comment: And what's the wanted result?

Comment: just like this `09-22-11`

Comment: this  questions appears to be an orphan (user15404864 does not link to anything)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that `TransactionDate` is actually *text*.  You could use `STR_TO_DATE` to first convert your date string to a bona fide datetime, then use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the output text you want.

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
           STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(TransactionDate, 15), '%a %b %d %Y'),
           '%m-%d-%y') AS TransactionDateOut
FROM `Transaction`;
```

### Demo